# How do i parse this JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the JSON:

```
{"jobs":[{"name":"PR-BVT","lastBuild":{"result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1303358462150}},{"name":"PR-DBT-MYSQL","lastBuild":{"result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1302057202000}},{"name":"PR-DBT-POSTGRESQL","lastBuild":{"result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1302057202000}},{"name":"PR-FUNCT","lastBuild":{"result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1303358496244}},{"name":"PR-LOADT","lastBuild":{"result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1302057202000}},{"name":"PR-MAIN","lastBuild":{"result":"UNSTABLE","timestamp":1303358515506}},{"name":"PR-SECT","lastBuild":{"result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1302057211000}},{"name":"PR-WEB-BVT","lastBuild":{"result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1303358471795}},{"name":"praefectus-qa","lastBuild":{"result":"FAILURE","timestamp":1303358496583}},{"name":"praefectus_main","lastBuild":{"result":"FAILURE","timestamp":1303358476843}},{"name":"praefectus_today","lastBuild":{"result":"FAILURE","timestamp":1303358477786}},{"name":"prefectus-qa-1","lastBuild":{"result":"FAILURE","timestamp":1303358480424}},{"name":"pygments","lastBuild":{"result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1303358482063}},{"name":"test-slave","lastBuild":{"result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1302057202000}}]}
```

and this I got from the URL on the browser

```
http://10.0.1.115:8080/api/json?tree=jobs[name,lastBuild[timestamp,result]]
```

What I have to do is to loop through the "jobs" in that data structure and add appropriate rows in the drawChart function, which is:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Builds Passed');
    data.addColumn('string', 'title1');
    data.addColumn('string', 'text1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Build Failed');
    data.addColumn('string', 'title2');
    data.addColumn('string', 'text2');
    data.addRows([
      [new Date(2011, 1 ,1), 30000, undefined, undefined, 40645, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2011, 2 ,2), 14045, undefined, undefined, 20374, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2011, 3 ,3), 55022, undefined, undefined, 50766, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2011, 4 ,4), 75284, undefined, undefined, 14334, 'Lemco','Build Failed'],
      [new Date(2011, 5 ,5), 41476, 'Build Passed','Tecore', 66467, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2011, 6 ,6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2011, 7 ,6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2011, 8 ,6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2011, 9 ,6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2011, 10 ,6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2011, 11 ,6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2011, 12 ,6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined, undefined]
    ]);
```

any ideas how ?

Comment: So the data is coming from a different domain? Then you have to use JSONP. How are you retrieving the data currently?

Comment: The data is currrently coming from an exposed API in the host by using something like http://10.0.1.115:8080/api/json?tree=jobs[name,lastBuild[timestamp,result]], i hope that answers your question, i have a feeling it did not

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: Don't use `undefined` to enter undefined values. There is no such keyword. Instead it's just an ordinary variable which just happens to be undefined. If someone would set it (`var undefined="Hello!"`) it wouldn't be undefined anymore and you'd have unwanted values in your table. Use `null` instead as Google suggests: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#addrow

Comment: I got that. But are you already retrieving the data in your JavaScript code?

Comment: can you add the code where you are getting the JSON from the above URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... the question doesn't say that the data is coming from a different domain. You can use a JSON parser ([like this one](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)) to parse your JSON result:

```
var jsonString = "/*your json here*/";
var result = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

then pass `result` into your function. Result will contain a standard JavaScript data structure that you can use to access your data. For example,

```
result.jobs[0].name //contains PR-BVT
```

Comment: You don’t need `JSON.parse` if it’s already an object literal. It’s only needed when it’s a string, which it isn’t in this case.

Comment: You're right Mathias... I edited my code to clarify that `jsonString` should be a string and not an object literal. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_It_Works).

Comment: any simple example you can provide ? please

Comment: The link I provided has all the explanations and examples you need.